# Use Azure Logic App to Delete Old Files in Azure file share

Tags: azure-storage-files

Have an Azure Storage Account with a File Share for backup files. Want to keep 5 days of files in that file share and automatically delete anything older than 5 days.

Trying to use a Logic App to perform this task but using the value LastModified doesn't pull the LastModified date off of the file. I just get Null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that  is a known problem and is mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3a62438-e0a3-4af2-8f6c-c00ad7b7a240/azure-file-storage-connector-returns-null-for-last-modified?forum=azurelogicapps). Instead, you can get the "LastModified" form "Get File Metadata" for each "value" after you get "List Files".